# How to add properties to record?

Tags: f#-giraffe

I want to

1. extract jwt from http request
2. get claims from jwt
3. add claims to command model

like below

```ml
let middleware<'a> handler next (ctx: HttpContext) =
    task {
        let token = ctx.Request.Headers.["Authorization"].ToString()
        match token with
        | Bearer token ->
            let claims = getClaims token
            let! command = ctx.BindJsonAsync<'a>()
            // how to add claims to command?
            return! handler command next ctx

        | _ ->
            return! RequestErrors.unauthorized "Bearer" "Commerce" authenticationError next ctx
    }
```

How do I do the 3rd step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 4 options I can think of here.

1. You could add the JWT authorisation properties onto your command model and avoid binding them when you call `BindJsonAsync` then you populate it. This is my least favourite approach as you end up with properties which could be set by whoever sends the model.
2. You could use anonymous records to add additional properties to your record type. This approach you need to know the type of command which may cause issues here as it looks like you're using generic model binding. It also makes it harder to pass types across binary boundaries.

```
type CommandHandler = { Command : string; Entity : int }
let command = { Command = "Update"; Entity = 1 }
let authorisedCommand = {| command with AuthToken = "ey ===" |}
```

3. You could create a new type which is a copy of the type you use for model binding except with the additional properties but that means again you need to know the fixed type you're copying and you also need to copy all of the properties.

```
type CommandHandlerModel = { Command : string; Id : int }
type AuthorisedCommandHandlerModel = { Command : string; Id : int }
let commandHandler = { CommandHandlerModel.Command = "Update"; Id = 1 }
let authedCommandHandler = { AuthporosedCommandHandlerModel.Command = "Update"; Id = 1 }
```

4. The approach I would probably take though is to wrap your command in a new type like this:

```
type CommandHandlerModel = { Command : string; Id : int }
type AuthorisedCommandHandlerModel<'a> = { CommandModel : 'a; AuthToken : string }
let! command = ctx.BindJsonAsync<'a>()
let authedCommand = { CommandModel = command; AuthToken = claims }
```

I've felt this compositional approach is a more idiomatic way of solving the problem and an approach I've used in the past

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I want to write a generic model binding as a middleware. I think the 4th approach is the best option for me.